# ggplot graph with line above and below the median

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, median, gplots

I am trying to make a ggplot graph with two regression lines: One below and the other above the median to depict potential effect of age in the sample.
So fa, I have tried:
geom_hline (aes(yintercept = median(df$y)
I do not get anything. I can also have two graphs, one with one line and the second one with the other line and combine them, but I haven't had success.
Any help?

Yacila

geom_hline (aes(yintercept = median(df$y)

Expected a line above the mean

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question and provide the information mentioned here to improve your post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Did you call `ggplot()'` first? As in `ggplot(df) + geom_hline(yintercept=median(y))`

Comment: Are you fitting a regression line for those above the median age and another for those below the median age?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The effect of age" sounds like age is on the x-axis. Here is a minimal example for two regression lines on either side of the median on the x-axis with `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
data(mtcars)
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = qsec)) + geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(data = filter(mtcars, mpg <= median(mpg)), method = "lm", size = 1.2, se=F) +
  geom_smooth(data = filter(mtcars, mpg > median(mpg)), method = "lm", size = 1.2, se=F) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=median(mtcars$mpg))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Credit

goes to [Marco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75713894/8245406) for pointing out that

> "The effect of age" sounds like age is on the x-axis.

---

### Answer

Include a `group` aesthetic on the condition of age being below or above the median. This will split the data into two groups.

```r
df1 <- iris[1:2]
names(df1) <- c("y", "age")

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df1, aes(age, y, group = age < median(age))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = median(df1$age)) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>